# assert не срабатывает

Tags: python

В txt собраны записи построчно "Response [200]" и далее ссылка на файл. assert стоит на любое другое, кроме "Response [200]". и вот он не работает. Почему?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
f = open('files.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
for line in f.readlines():
    print (line)
resp = '<Response [200]>'
assert resp, 'file not found'
f.close()
```

Comment: `assert resp == '<Response [200]>', 'file not found'`

Comment: @ gil9red Не, и так не работат(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

OK_RESP = '<Response [200]>'

with open('files.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print(line)
        assert line == OK_RESP, 'file not found'
```

Comment: Вот с таким логом свалился после первой же ссылки<Response [200]> https://www.mt.......
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/python/chench.py", line 6, in <module>
    assert line == OK_RESP, 'file not found'
AssertionError: file not found

Comment: @СергейБогданов, так это и значит что assert сработал) Вы чего-то другого хотели?

Comment: @СергейБогданов, значит у вас `line` не соответствует значению в `OK_RESP`, т.е. assert сработал -- в нем вы пишите хорошее условие, а сработает assert если условие является False

Comment: Верно) Спасибо всем